# shadow removal in OpenCV 2.4.3

Tags: c++, image-processing, opencv, background, shadow

I am using OpenCV 2.4.3 (the latest version) to detect foreground from video streams using built-in [GMG](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/gpu/doc/video.html?highlight=gmg#gpu%3a%3aGMG_GPU) algorithm. The result works fine, but I want to also remove the foreground shadow, in my case, the shadow of a moving person. I couldn't find a parameter that is similar to "shadow detection parameter" of MoG in opencv2.4.2 for removing shadows. I've read the original [paper](http://goldberg.berkeley.edu/pubs/acc-2012-visual-tracking-final.pdf) for this, and found "Heuristic Confidence Model" part might be helpful, but still couldn't handle it in my code. Can someone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't help you directly, but I can point you towards the work of [Graham Finlayson](http://www.uea.ac.uk/computing/People/Faculty/Graham+Finlayson) who has done a lot of work into shadow removal from colour images. See for example:

- [Entropy Minimization for Shadow Removal](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11263-009-0243-z)
- [On the Removal of Shadows from Images](http://www.computer.org/csdl/trans/tp/2006/01/i0059-abs.html)

Comment: Actually I've solved this problem using my own way. But I also appreciate your answer.

Comment: You may also want to see this recent [review paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1304.1233) on shadow detection / removal. The paper contains links to the source code for various shadow detection algorithms.

Comment: To expand on my above comment: the source code for the various shadow detection algorithms is [here](http://arma.sourceforge.net/shadows/)