# Remove colour 'shades'/shadows

Tags: c++, opencv

What OpenCV functions can be used to ignore/filter out colour 'variation'/shades of a colour (shadows, reflections, etc.)?

Shouldn't removing the Value/Intensity channel from HSV images create colour blocks and reduce/eliminate 'colour variance'/shades of white due to light?

If you look at the following image, the *walls are painted one solid consistent colour of cream/white. But it's colour varies alot because of shadows and light reflections. *Referring to the white walls above the lockers.

[image]

I thought that if I convert the image to HSV then remove the Value/Intensity channel that I can filter out those wall reflections and shadows, colour variation - ie, the light. Then I just colour reduce the image and I should have a large colour block for the wall (above the lockers)? Ie, see the wall in it's true form/colour as one solid colour block.

But from my image above you can see the wall is not one solid/consistent colour after removing the V channel and after colour reducing.

```
void removeIntensity()
{
    Mat hsv, hs, reducedHs;
    Mat image = imread("../../Book_Tutorials/images/11.jpg");

    if (image.cols > 300) {
        float scale = 300.0 / (float)image.rows;
        resize(image, image, { int(scale * image.cols), 300 });
    }

    cvtColor(image, hsv, CV_BGR2HSV);

    std::vector<Mat> hsvChannels;
    split(hsv, hsvChannels);

    // Set value/intensity to constant value: can I remove those channels completely?
    hsvChannels[2] = 0;

    merge(hsvChannels, hs);

    reduce(hs, reducedHs, 6);

    imshow("image", image);
    imshow("hsv", hsv);
    imshow("hs", hs);
    imshow("reducedHs", reducedHs);
}

void reduce(const Mat& hsv, Mat& reduced, int nColours)
{
    int n = hsv.rows * hsv.cols;
    std::vector<int> labels;
    Mat centres;
    Mat collapsedImage = hsv.reshape(1, n);
    collapsedImage.convertTo(collapsedImage, CV_32F);

    kmeans(collapsedImage, nColours, labels, TermCriteria(TermCriteria::EPS + TermCriteria::COUNT, 10, 1.0),
        3, KMEANS_PP_CENTERS, centres);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

        collapsedImage.at<float>(i, 0) = centres.at<float>(labels[i], 0);
        collapsedImage.at<float>(i, 1) = centres.at<float>(labels[i], 1);
        collapsedImage.at<float>(i, 2) = centres.at<float>(labels[i], 2);
    }

    reduced = collapsedImage.reshape(3, hsv.rows);
    reduced.convertTo(reduced, CV_8U);
}
```

Comment: seems to be a wrong place to ask

Comment: It is not an obvious problem. You can find pointer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13291469/shadow-removal-in-opencv-2-4-3?rq=1

Comment: I would look into edge detection algorithms, as those might be what you are looking for.

Comment: [This paper](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.11.5938&rep=rep1&type=pdf) explains how to play around with color spaces. One of them has the property of begin invariant to different illuminations. I'd start from that.

Comment: @Acrethaen edge detection? Why?